# Dapper Orm delete exception

Tags: c#, dapper

I'am triying to delete with dapper orm. But im getting this exception:

> When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if
>   you have keys other  than Id

My code is shown below:

```
public void DeleteRole(int ID)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            conn.Query("DELETE FROM [Role] WHERE ID=@ID", new {ID=ID });
        }
    }
```

Any idea?

Comment: The code changed *drastically* on your edit. Is this the code that's throwing? And why are you using `Query` here instead of `Execute`?

Comment: I updated my code. I posted wrong code before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue here is that you're using `Query` instead of `Execute`. The `Query` method is trying to find a column named `Id` to build the result set and can't because it's not a query.

Answer (score 11):

Either specify return type for query (integer)

```
int rowsCount = conn.Query<int>("DELETE FROM [Role] WHERE ID = @ID", new { ID });
```

Or use Execute method, as Michael pointed

NOTE: You don't need to open connection manually - Dapper will open it for you.

BTW generic query will work for your original question:

```
int id = conn.Query<int>(@"INSERT [Role] (Name, CreatedDate,UpdatedDate) 
                           VALUES (@Name, @CreatedDate,@UpdatedDate) 
                           SELECT CAST(scope_identity() as INT)", model).First();
```

Comment: +1 as the number of rows affected might be a nice return value there.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud thanks :) Already upvoted your answer, because its correct and Execute returns integer (affected rows count). Parametrized query just better fits to original question with SELECT statement